# Date range query on ObjectId in MongoDB using Spring REST pagination

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, rest, pagination

I need to do a date range query in the users collection. However it does not have a date field. I found some useful resources to convert time to ObjectId first then query on it in Mongodb shell:

```
>var idMin = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2018/1/1'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000")
>var idMax = ObjectId(Math.floor((new Date('2018/2/1'))/1000).toString(16) + "0000000000000000")
>db.users.find({_id:{$gt: idMin, $lt: idMax}})
```

My project will get the time range at frontend, convert it to ObjectId string (idMin, idMax) then make a request to Spring REST API to fetch the data. How can I implement the query using Spring with pageable? Is there an ObjectId class in spring mongodb lib?

User.java:

```
@Document(collection = "users")
    public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private int age;
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/users/{idMin}/{idMax}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {

    Page<User> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    //TODO: query on id range {idMin, idMax}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like

Calling Code:

```
ObjectId idMin = new ObjectId(new Date("2018/1/1"));
ObjectId idMax = new ObjectId(new Date("2018/2/1"));
Pageable pages = new PageRequest(1, 2);

Page<User> results = repository.findByObjectIdsAndPages(idMin, idMax, pages);
```

Repository

```
 @Query("{_id:{$gt: ?0, $lt: ?1}}")
 Page<User> findByObjectIdsAndPages(ObjectId idMin, ObjectId idMax, Pageable pages);
```

Comment: I will give it a  try. How to import ObjectId?

Comment: It's in mongodb bson package. Try org.bson.types.ObjectId